# What happens to non-min values in a PriorityQueue (Java)?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I'm trying to understand why the answer to this question is C. According to a lecture I just watched, the PriorityQueue keeps the smallest element at the front and the rest doesn't matter or has no set order. So when adding a value less than the current min, the current min is moved to the end of the queue or to the back of the list and the new min takes its place at the front. That logic doesn't seem to work here so I think I'm missing something. In the video it was mentioned that index 0 wasn't going to be used but I couldn't find a reason why. I wonder if this is what I'm missing. What's going on with the rest of the values? [image]

This is what is happening..
46
26 46
18 46 26
15 18 26 46
9 15 26 46 18
9 15 26 46 18 38
9 15 12 46 18 38 26
9 15 12 45 18 38 26 46

This is what I get using the logic I explained above
46
26 46
18 46 26
15 46 26 18
9 46 26 18 15
9 46 26 18 15 38
9 46 26 18 15 38 12
9 46 26 18 15 38 12 45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The priority queue organizes the elements (if it is a min queue) so that the root is the minimum element.

Note that in this example, the queue is backed by a heap data structure and the heap is stored as an array. A heap maintains the property that the root is larger than its children (left and right) and that each of its children share the same property in that each of the child nodes is larger than its children. This property of a heap is the key in answering the question you posted.

https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/PLDS210/heaps.html

The text above has a schematic on insertion to a heap and that would answer your question. In the example elements are inserted one after the other and they propagate upwards (called siftup in some implementations) to its place in the heap data structure and to add n elements requires nlogn complexity.

I would recommend drawing the heap as a binary tree by repeatedly inserting the elements and you would also come to the same conclusion which is (c).

If you are interested in experimenting with some java code, you could download two classes for an elementary implementation of a heap and play with them. They are at:

http://khanna111.com/wordPressBlog/2013/06/

Note that this implementation uses the "siftDown" approach wherein it translates a given "n" element array into a heap in o (n) complexity. You could download the code and play with it and implement the "siftUp" approach on your own to garner an understanding of the heap data structure. Note the code is in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The zero'th element is not used because the priority queue is implemented using an array heap.

The array heap has the property that position `i`'th element's two children are at position `(i * 2)` and `(i * 2) + 1`. Also, a node at position `i`'s parent is thus at position `(i / 2)` in the array.

This would not be possible if the root node has a position 0; multiplication would not work in that case. Excluding the first position, `0`, would allow a tree structure to be made using the above two properties. This would allow for fast operation of the heap using constant time array operations.

When an item is removed from the heap (in other words item at position `1` is removed from the array), it is replaced with the last item in the array heap. This value is then "bubbled down", swapping with its smaller child until the min-heap conditionals are met (a node's children are both bigger than itself).

Comment: Hope I'm not too late.. :)

Answer (score 0):

`PriorityQueue` is an abstract data structure based on `min-heap`. so there is definitely an order between elements on the heap i.e objects with minimum values will be closer to root. But the goal of a `min-heap` is to find min element not ordering the elements. Hence if you traverse the elements you will find there is no particular order in which they are placed on the heap.